# Extracting columns from a table in hive results in NULL table

Tags: jquery, sql, hadoop, hive, null

I am working with Hive. I have a table tbofcars2 and I am creating another table modelbodyfuelprice from tbofcars2 while selecting only 4 columns.

The top 20 rows of tbofcars2 look like this:

[image]

Code I am using:

```
hive> create table modelbodyfuelprice as select model, body_type, fuel_type, price_eur from tbofcars2;
hive> select * from modelbodyfuelprice limit 10;
```

This gives and output:

[image]

Could you please tell me why the values in the columns are not getting extracted the way they are and all we get is null values?

Thanks.

Comment: You would seem to have a bunch of rows in `tbofcars2` that have `NULL` values in them.  You should probably filter them out when you create the table.

Comment: I agree. However, if I use the is NOT NULL statement, I end up with a table that has no values (not even NULL) at all.

Comment: Could you please go to the HDFS location of the new hive table and check if the data is present by doing hadoop fs -cat? do describe formatted tbofcars2, you'll get the HDFS location.

Comment: what query did you use to create tbofcars2? Is it an external table?